# Between vs From To

Tags: grammaticality

I have found phrases like:

"I will be outside from 10am to 1pm"
or
"I will be outside between 10am and 1pm"

I have 3 questions:

- What is more colloquial?
- What is considered adherent to the formal English grammar?
- Is there any difference between them?

Comment: At the risk of sounding nit picky, the second phrase should be "I will be outside between 10am AND 1pm".

Comment: valid feedback, @KyleP.

Comment: They could mean different things.  The first means you’ll be outside for 3 hours.  The second would still be true if you were only outside from 12:00 to 12:15.